# Calling a parent instance variable from a sub class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have to call an instance variable initialized in a parent Class from a sub class.
I know that I can solve using "@@profile" instead of "@profile" but it needs to be thread-safe.

```
class ParentClass

    attr_reader :profile

    def initialize(profile:)
        @profile = profile
    end

    def call_sub
        SubClass.new().run()
    end

end

class SubClass < ParentClass

    def initialize()
        @retries = 0
    end

    def run()
        puts "PROFILE: #{@profile.inspect}"
    end

end

pc = ParentClass.new(profile: "Me")
pc.call_sub

p = ParentClass.new(profile: "Me")
puts "PROFILE: #{p.profile}"
```

**ruby test.rb**

```
PROFILE: nil <--- Why is nil ?
PROFILE: Me
```

Comment: Because `SubClass` overwrites initialize, takes no arguments, and does not call super. Change the `SubClass#initialize` to `def initialize(profile:); super; @retries= 0;end` and change `ParentClass#call_sub` to `SubClass.new(profile: self.profile).run` another alternative (probably better) is remove initialize from `SubClass` and define `def retries; @retries ||= 0; end` ( you will still have to pass the profile kwarg to `new` in `call_sub` then everything will work as expected.

Comment: In addition to what engineerminsky said about your initializer, you can't treat a mutable shared variable or object as thread-safe. You probably need to use Thread-local variables or use mutexes on access to an injected Profile object. That probably means rethinking your architecture, or reframing what you're really trying to do with the Profile object across threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding `ParentClass#initialize`.

Ruby does not magically invoke overridden methods. That would kind of defeat the point of overriding in the first place: for example, often, the reason why you override a method in a subclass, is that the subclass implementation can make use of its knowledge of the subclass to improve performance. It wouldn't make sense for Ruby to invoke the un-optimized version *in addition* to the optimized one.

However, another big purpose of overriding is *differential code reuse*: reusing code by only implementing the difference in behavior. In order to do that, Ruby has the `super` keyword, which allows you to retry the method lookup starting one level up in the ancestors chain.

Here's what that would look like in your case:

```ruby
class SubClass < ParentClass
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @retries = 0
  end
end
```

This solves the problem with the un-initialized instance variable.

However, there are several other problems with your code. For example, here:

```ruby
SubClass.new().run()
```

You are sending the message `new` to `SubClass` without any arguments. By default, [`Class#new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) is implemented roughly like this:

```ruby
class Class
  def new(...)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(...)
    obj
  end
end
```

[Technically, `initialize` is `private`, so we need to break encapsulation here by using something more like `obj.__send__(:initialize, ...)`.]

In other words, `new` passes its arguments on to `initialize`. But you have defined `ParentClass#initialize` with one mandatory keyword parameter `profile:`, so theoretically, we need to pass an argument to `super` … but what should we pass? So, instead, we have defined `SubClass#initialize` to take arguments and pass them on to `ParentClass#initialize`.

However, you are passing no arguments to `SubClass::new` here, that we could pass on, and in fact, it isn't clear what arguments we *could* pass here.

I would like to help you here, but to be honest, the code simply does not make sense, so I don't see how to fix it. Superclasses *must never* know about their subclasses, in fact, they typically *cannot* know about their subclasses: many languages allow you to add subclasses after the fact, and Ruby is no exception. Therefore, a superclass knowing about its subclass is a sign that something in your design is very, very, very wrong.

Also note that the very idea of a "parent instance variable" does not make sense: "parent" refers to the *class hierarchy*, but instance variables belong to *instances* … that's why they are called "instance" variables, after all.